# Why does using mod with int64_t operand makes this function 150% slower?

Tags: c, performance

The `max_rem` function computes the maximum remainder that `(a+1)^n + (a-1)^n` leaves when divided by `a²` for `n = 1, 2, 3...`. The `main` calls `max_rem` on every `a` from `3` to `999`. Complete code:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int max_rem(int a) {
    int max_r = 0;
    int m = a * a; // <-------- offending line
    int r1 = a+1, r2 = a-1;
    for(int n = 1; n <= a*a; n++) {
        r1 = (r1 * (a + 1)) % m;
        r2 = (r2 * (a - 1)) % m;
        int r = (r1 + r2) % m;
        if(max_r < r) 
            max_r = r;
    }
    return max_r;
}

int main() {
    int64_t sum = 0;
    for(int a = 3; a < 1000; a++)
        sum += max_rem(a);

    printf("%ld\n", sum);
}
```

If I change line 6 from:

```
int m = a * a;
```

to

```
int64_t m = a * a;
```

the whole computation becames about **150% slower**. I tried both with `gcc 5.3` and `clang 3.6`.

With `int`:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -O3 -Wall -o 120 120.c
$ time(./120)

real    0m3.823s
user    0m3.816s
sys     0m0.000s
```

with `int64_t`:

```
$ time(./120)

real    0m9.861s
user    0m9.836s
sys     0m0.000s
```

and yes, I'm on a **64-bit system**. Why does this happen?

I've always assumed that using `int64_t` is safer and more portable and "the modern way to write C"® and wouldn't harm performances on 64bits systems for numeric code. Is this assumption erroneous?

**EDIT**: just to be clear: **the slowdown persists even if you change *every* variable to `int64_t`**. So this is not a problem with mixing `int` and `int64_t`.

Comment: Try changing all ints to (u)int64_ts.

Comment: You're mixing `int64_t` with `int`. Use the same type throughout your function.

Comment: If he's already using 64-bit, why does it matter? At the end of the day, shouldn't the same assembly be generated? I think this is a really good question.

Comment: Even if you change everything to int64_t the slowdown is the same. I edited to clarify.

Comment: Did you check "sizeof(int)"? It's 4 even with 64-bit Windows because using [LLP64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models)

Comment: Check the assembler code, identify hotspots and look up instruction timing or benchmark these sections seperately. Division cannot be performed in a single cycle without a giant bunch of logic ressources.

Comment: @jdarthenay he's using *nix terminal. But yes, int is 32 bits on most platforms nowadays

Comment: When the silicon designer thinks it makes little sense to make 64 bit operations as fast as 32bits, then they won't do it.

Comment: @user3528438: Atom saves some power / transistors by having some 64bit ops be slower than 32bit (e.g. multiply), but on non-Atom CPUs almost everything is as fast as they can make it.  Division is just hard, so there's no way 64b division could be as fast as 32b, unless they slowed down 32b division for no reason!  The OP unfortunately didn't say anything about the hardware they tested on.  The speed ratio between 64 and 32bit division varies between microarchitectures, but it's always significant (for division only).

Comment: You know you can just do `time ./120`, right?  You don't need to fork a `(subshell)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've always assumed that using int64_t is safer and more portable and "the modern way to write C"® and wouldn't harm performances on 64bits systems for numeric code. Is this assumption erroneous?

It seems so to me. You can find the instruction timings in [Intel's Software Optimization Reference manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) (appendix C, table C-17 General Purpose Instructions on page 645):

```
    IDIV r64   Throughput 85-100 cycles per instruction
    IDIV r32   Throughput 20-26 cycles per instruction
```

Comment: It is not necessarily the type that is the issue, it is the type-conversion required when you mix types and force the conversion from one type to another that adds additional processing requirements.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But it seems to me that if Intel says that 64-bit div/mod is slower than 32-bit div/mod, it will remain that way no matter how fast you make the conversions. Though it is true that avoiding the conversions may be able to reduce the slowdown to less than 150%.

Comment: Addition and subtraction are fast, but not multiplication and division. Division is even worse because you can't paralellize the computation like the other 3

Comment: The assumption is fine for everything except division.  BTW, [compiler output](https://godbolt.org/g/BNc09K) confirms that even the version inlined into `main` uses `idiv rcx` when `max_rem` uses `int64_t` for its locals.  Any conversion overhead is going to be totally hidden by the slowness of three `idiv`s per iteration.  `movsx` is very cheap.  The loop-carried dependency chain is just an add of the results, so we're only throughput bound, not latency.

Comment: Those numbers from Intel's guide are similar to what [Agner Fog's insn tables with numbers from experimental testing show](http://agner.org/optimize/): Intel Haswell: `idiv r32`: **one per 8-11c** throughput (22-29c latency, 9 uops).  `idiv r64`: **one per 24-81c** throughput (39-103c latency, 59 uops).  Unlike most instructions, division has data-dependent performance, and is only partially pipelined (div unit can't accept one input per clock).  Skylake: 32b: one per 6c, 64b: one per 24-90c.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: You see different performance with the change of types because you are measuring different computations -- one with all 32-bit data, the other with partially or all 64-bit data.

> I've always assumed that using int64_t is safer and more portable and "the modern way to write C"®

`int64_t` is the safest and most portable (among conforming C99 and C11 compilers) way to refer to a 64-bit signed integer type with no padding bits and a two's complement representation, if the implementation in fact provides such a type.  Whether using this type actually makes your code more portable depends on whether the code depends on any of those specific characteristics of integer representation, and on whether you are concerned with portability to environments that do not provide such a type.

> and wouldn't harm performances on 64bits systems for numeric code. Is this assumption erroneous?

`int64_t` is specified to be a `typedef`.  On any given system, using `int64_t` is semantically identical to directly using the type that underlies the typedef on that system.  You will see no performance difference between those alternatives.

However, your line of reasoning and question seem to belie an assumption: either that on the system where you perform your tests, the basic type underlying `int64_t` is `int`, or that 64-bit arithmetic will perform identically to 32-bit arithmetic on that system.  Neither of those assumptions is justified.  It is by no means guaranteed that C implementations for 64-bit systems will make `int` a 64-bit type, and in particular, neither GCC not Clang for x86_64 does so.  Moreover, C has nothing whatever to say about the relative performance of arithmetic on different types, and as others have pointed out, native x86_64 integer division instructions are in fact slower for 64-bit operands than for 32-bit operands.  Other platforms might exhibit other differences.

Comment: RE: last paragraph: I think the OP was under the impression that arithmetic on `int64_t` and `int32_t` were the same speed, which is true except for division.  (Or multiply on pre-silvermont Atom).  Of course `int` isn't 64bit in either of the tests; the [AMD64 SysV ABI specifies that it's 32b](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), and both compilers are targeting the same ABI.

Comment: @PeterCordes, fair enough.  I have updated my answer to accommodate that interpretation of the OP's question.  The bottom line remains that it is not, in general, reasonable to expect the same behavior from different computations.

Answer (score 1):

Integer division / modulo is extremely slow compared to any other operation.  (And is dependent on data size, unlike most operations on modern hardware, see the end of this answer)

**For repeated use of the same modulus, you will get *much* better performance from finding the multiplicative inverse for your integer divisor**.  Compilers do this for you for compile-time constants, but it's moderately expensive in time and code-size to do it at run-time, so with current compilers you have to decide for yourself when it's worth doing.

It takes some CPU cycles up front, but they're amortized over 3 divisions per iteration.

The reference paper for this idea is [Granlund and Montgomery's 1994 paper](https://gmplib.org/~tege/divcnst-pldi94.pdf), back when divide was only 4x as expensive as multiply on P5 Pentium hardware.  That paper talks about implementing the idea in gcc 2.6, as well as the mathematical proof that it works.

[Compiler output](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-std%3Dgnu11+-fverbose-asm+-O3+-mtune%3Dhaswell',source:'int+div13+(int+a)+%7B+return+a/13%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+mod13+(int+a)+%7B+return+a%2513%3B+%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) shows the kind of code that division by a small constant turns into:

```
## clang 3.8 -O3 -mtune=haswell  for x86-64 SysV ABI: first arg in rdi
int mod13 (int a) { return a%13; }
    movsxd  rax, edi               # sign-extend 32bit a into 64bit rax
    imul    rcx, rax, 1321528399   # gcc uses one-operand 32bit imul (32x32 => 64b), which is faster on Atom but slower on almost everything else.  I'm showing clang's output because it's simpler
    mov     rdx, rcx
    shr     rdx, 63                # 0 or 1: extract the sign bit with a logical right shift
    sar     rcx, 34                # only use the high half of the 32x32 => 64b multiply
    add     ecx, edx               # ecx = a/13.   # adding the sign bit accounts for the rounding semantics of C integer division with negative numbers
    imul    ecx, ecx, 13           # do the remainder as  a - (a/13)*13
    sub     eax, ecx
    ret
```

And yes, all this is cheaper than a `div` instruction, for throughput and latency.

I tried to google for simpler descriptions or calculators, and found stuff [like this page](http://www.flounder.com/multiplicative_inverse.htm).

---

On modern Intel CPUs, 32 and 64b multiply has one per cycle throughput, and 3 cycle latency.  (i.e. it's fully pipelined).

Division is only partially pipelined (the div unit can't accept one input per clock), and unlike most instructions, has data-dependent performance:

From [Agner Fog's insn tables](http://agner.org/optimize/) (see also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki):

- Intel Core2:  `idiv r32`: one per 12-36c throughput (18-42c latency, 4 uops).
  `idiv r64`: one per 28-40c throughput (39-72c latency, 56 uops).  (unsigned `div` is significantly faster: 32 uops, one per 18-37c throughput)
- Intel Haswell: `div/idiv r32`: one per 8-11c throughput (22-29c latency, 9 uops).
  `idiv r64`: one per 24-81c throughput (39-103c latency, 59 uops).  (unsigned `div`: one per 21-74c throughput, 36 uops)
- Skylake: `div/idiv r32`: one per 6c throughput (26c latency, 10 uops).
  64b: one per 24-90c throughput (42-95c latency, 57 uops).  (unsigned `div`: one per 21-83c throughput, 36 uops)

So on Intel hardware, unsigned division is cheaper for 64bit operands, the same for 32b operands.

The throughput differences between 32b and 64b `idiv` can easily account for 150% performance.  [Your code](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-std%3Dgnu11+-fverbose-asm+-O3+-mtune%3Dhaswell',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB5wBd0E8AOCDOAdABYB8AUKJLIqvunCAPYkXnZ6IBmSGAbABYA%2BuiQBbLBgDc5chnEBDAB5CATgjEAKCfIUBKJAG9ySU%2BMlhRY5WqQBeJAAYZZ8/LH2kCpACovUpAB6QNQAWnCI8KQmLi4EMEYwAHMkKHAEEzMdSyRVAEZPBQBqPIAaXIAmQtC8lzMuJlVNeTBPWqRWlAcFHwUAsCKig2NXV3zPTXG/TW8ipDy9AwBScTrRyonVKunvUPnFpBWxNdHs0VVNgrmt5dXM9ZAubRsLlFyDe/Wsl89VE4BfT7qdAwVStawqP7kQFyHLWcCaYaffjCUT4GAeBzOT4NJq6TwAZgC3jeeUc5OJgz0n1c6I8RQcELUGhmehknxwqgwTwAREsoHAADpgHnlOls6FAAA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) is completely throughput bound, since you have plenty of independent operations, especially between loop iterations.  The loop-carried dependency is just a `cmov` for the max operation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question can come only from looking at the assembly. I'd run it on my box for my curiosity but it's 3000 miles away:( so I'll have to guess and you look and post your findings here...
Just add -S to your compiler command line.

I believe that with int64 the compilers are doing something different than with int32. That is, they cannot use use some optimization that is available to them with int32.

Maybe gcc replaces the division with multiplication only with int32? There should be a 'if( x < 0 )' branch. Maybe gcc can eliminate it with int32?

I somehow don't believe the performance can be so different if they both do plain 'idiv'

Comment: gcc replaces division with a multiplicative inverse (full-multiply by magic constant + shifting and adds) only for division by a constant.  It would be a performance win to compute the multiplicative inverse at run time (if one exists), since the OP's loop uses the same modulo repeatedly, but gcc doesn't do this for you.  It would create a huge increase in code-size, which even if gcc could do it, might not always be justified or desired.  (The multiplicative inverse only gives you the quotient, but you can then multiply again and subtract to get the remainder.)